# Background jobs in shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a shell script `script.sh` with a command `cmd` launched in background within, that is:

```
#!/bin/bash
…
cmd &
…
```

If I open a terminal emulator (I've tried xfce4-terminal and gnome-terminal) and run `script.sh` within, my command `cmd` is effectively executed, and executed in background, as expected.

But, if I open a terminal emulator from the previous one (or at the beginning of my desktop session, which is my real use case), and execute my script by

```
xfce4-terminal -H -x script.sh (or gnome-terminal -x script.sh)
```

the command `cmd` is not executed anymore.

I found that I can force it to be executed by putting `set -m` in my script, but I don't understand why it is necessary (nor sufficient, actually) in this case, and not in the previous one. Indeed, if I put a `set -o` in my script, I obtain the same output in both cases.

Can someone explain this to me, and / or tell me the right way to proceed with background jobs in shell scripts? Thanks!

---

EDIT: Actually, `cmd` is executed in both cases, but in the second one, it is immediatly killed by the termination of `script.sh`. To prevent this, one can use `nohup`, but it's not enough, and it's the strangest thing for me: one also has to put `sleep 1`, or something like that, to allow the process to be properly launched in background, and dissociated from the parent shell, otherwise it is also killed.

I really don't understand this difference in behavior between the two shells, since both are non interactive, as stated in a previous comment.

Comment: How are you sure `cmd` is not executing? Is it easily & uniquely found in ps's output (and lasts long enough to find), or does it make a sound or other GUI indication?

Comment: @Xen2050 Typically, I choose for `cmd` something that can be seen in a task manager, like `sleep n` with `n` big enough. But one can choose something with a GUI, like `firefox` or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered on [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480934/process-killed-before-being-launched-in-background) (see also additional comments below the answer). It's a question of who sends the SIGHUP signal to whom and when. And an alternative to `set -m / set +m` around `cmd &` in `script.sh` is `trap '' HUP / trap - HUP`.

Answer (score 1):

If You open `xfce4-trminal` or `gnome-terminal` (or other terminal) Your shell is in interactive mode. Every script is run in interactive mode.

If You run `script.sh` through

```
xfce4-terminal -H -x script.sh
```

or

```
gnome-terminal -x script.sh
```

or other terminal, Your shell is in non-interactive mode.

Scripts may be forced to run in interactive mode with the `-i` option or with a `#!/bin/bash -i` header. Be aware that this can cause erratic script behavior or show error messages even when no error is present.

What is `set -m`? It's **monitor mode**. Background processes run in a separate process group and a  line  containing  their exit status is printed upon their completion. It is enabled by default for interactive shells.

What is `set -o`? It's write the current settings of the options to standard output in an unspecified format.

Why `set -o` works?

> The  −o  option  was adopted from the KornShell to address user needs. In addition to its generally friendly interface, −o is needed to provide the vi command line editing mode, for which historical practice yields no single-letter option name. (Although it might have been possible to invent such a letter, it was recognized that other editing modes would be developed and −o provides ample  name space for describing such extensions.)
>
> Historical  implementations are inconsistent in the format used for −o option status reporting. The +o format without an option-argument was added to allow portable access to the options that can be saved and then later restored using, for instance, a dot script.

Anyway, `set -m` is preferred way.

Comment: No… the shell in your terminal is interactive, but the one invoked to run the script is not. That's what I observe, in particular, by putting `set -o` in my script: in both cases, its output is the same, in particular concerning monitor mode, which is set to off (the default in non interactive mode). I don't put `set -o` to see if it works, but to see its output.